# NotSerializableException while transforming XML using XSLT in Saxon 10.6 HE

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxon, saxon-js

I am trying to transform XML using XSLT in Saxon 10.6 HE. Getting error as below.

Error: java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: net.sf.saxon.om.StructuredQName

Input XML:

```
<create>
   <article>
      <identifier>Test</identifier>
   </article>
      <article>
      <identifier>Test123</identifier>
   </article>
</create>
<update>
   <article>
      <identifier>Test</identifier>
   </article>
</update>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  xmlns:my="http://example.com/my-functions"
  expand-text="yes">
  
<xsl:variable name="vPop" as="element()*">
<item path="/header/txCtry">Test</item>
<item path="/data/txSttlmInf/instgRmbrsmntAgt/BICFI">nijith</item>
<item path="/data/txCityCd">33</item>
 </xsl:variable>
 
 <xsl:variable name="new-nodes">
   <xsl:sequence select="my:subTree($vPop/@path/concat(.,'/',string(..)))"/>
 </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
  <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
    <xsl:sequence select="my:merge(*, $new-nodes/*)"/>
  </xsl:template>


 <xsl:function name="my:merge" as="node()*">
   <xsl:param name="node1" as="node()*"/>
   <xsl:param name="node2" as="node()*"/>
   <xsl:for-each-group select="$node1, $node2" group-by="path()">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:sequence select="my:merge(@*, current-group()[2]/@*)"/>
       <xsl:sequence select="my:merge(node(), current-group()[2]/node())"/>
     </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:function>

 <xsl:function name="my:subTree" as="node()*">
   
   
  <xsl:param name="pPaths" as="xs:string*"/>

  <xsl:for-each-group select="$pPaths"
    group-adjacent=
        "substring-before(substring-after(concat(., '/'), '/'), '/')">
    <xsl:if test="current-grouping-key()">
     <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test=
          "substring-after(current-group()[1], current-grouping-key())">
         <xsl:element name=
           "{substring-before(concat(current-grouping-key(), '['), '[')}">

          <xsl:sequence select=
            "my:subTree(for $s in current-group()
                         return
                            concat('/',substring-after(substring($s, 2),'/'))
                             )
            "/>
        </xsl:element>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
       </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
     </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Java code:

```
    Source xslt = new StreamSource(new StringReader(inputXSLT));
    Source xml = new StreamSource(new StringReader(inputXML));
    StringWriter transformedXML = new StringWriter();

    Processor processor = new Processor(false);
    XsltCompiler compiler = processor.newXsltCompiler();
    XsltExecutable stylesheet = compiler.compile(xslt);
    Serializer out = processor.newSerializer(transformedXML);
    out.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.METHOD, "xml");
    out.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.INDENT, "yes");
    Xslt30Transformer transformer = stylesheet.load30();

    transformer.transform(xml, out);
    outputXML = transformedXML.toString();
```

Kindly help to resolve this issue. Is there any way to implement this without using Serializer.

Comment: Does that input without a single root element parse at all?

Comment: Hi @MartinHonnen After adding the root element it is working fine. Is there any other way to do the transformation in java code without using Serializer?

Comment: There are various overloads (of the `applyTemplates` method) that can return an XdmValue. But I kind of doubt the problem is related to the use of a Serializer, the parsing of an input that has not single root is not going to work, unless you use functions or methods to be able to deal with that like the XPath 3.1 function `parse-xml-fragment`.

Comment: It's a very strange error, and I can't reproduce it. I get what I would expect: an error message "Error on line 9 column 2 
  SXXP0003   Error reported by XML parser: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed."

Comment: I would add that Saxon never itself throws a `NotSerializableException`, and this exception has nothing to do with XML serialization (it relates to serialization of Java objects, which is something quite different). A Stack trace of the exception would help.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelKay for the response. Let me check whether I can get the Stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how you could parse that input lacking a single root element, if you want to do that you need the help of the XPath 3.1 `parse-xml-fragment` function

```
String inputXMLFragment = "<create>\n" +
            "   <article>\n" +
            "      <identifier>Test</identifier>\n" +
            "   </article>\n" +
            "      <article>\n" +
            "      <identifier>Test123</identifier>\n" +
            "   </article>\n" +
            "</create>\n" +
            "<update>\n" +
            "   <article>\n" +
            "      <identifier>Test</identifier>\n" +
            "   </article>\n" +
            "</update>";

XdmNode inputNode = (XdmNode) XdmFunctionItem.getSystemFunction(processor, new QName("http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions", "parse-xml-fragment"), 1)
                .call(processor, XdmAtomicValue.makeAtomicValue(inputXMLFragment));

...

transformer.applyTemplates(inputNode, out);
```

Comment: Hi @MartinHonnen, I have the XML with tag names containing spaces and starting with numbers. Is there any way to parse it? Sample XML: <root>
<B1>
  <Application Identifier>F</Application Identifier>
</B1>
<B3>
  <108:>212759999</108:>
  <121:>4f8a-a92d-cba1b4e07cf0</121:>
</B3>
<B4>
  <23B:>
    <4!c>CRDDED</4!c>
  </23B:>>
</B4>
</root>

Comment: @Nijith, neither can XML element names start with a digit nor can they contain spaces so that way standard XML processing is certainly not possible. Some XSLT processing chains allow you to feed other input like HTML or SGML but I don't know any format that would allow spaces in element names so I don't know an existing parser for such a format.

Comment: Thanks @MartinHonnen for the information.